# Dual booting Linux and Windows - which filesystem should I choose?

Tags: linux, usb, filesystems, dualboot

I want to have Linux on my SSD 250GB disk and two partitions on HDD (250GB for Windows and 750GB for data). And I would like to have access to this data when I am using Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) and Windows 10. What filesystem should I use? As I know Linux has support for reading NTFS files. But is there any solution that allows you to write NTFS data on Linux? I know that there is a FAT32 system that is very compatible with almost everything but is very old and maybe not good.

When I use Rufus to create a USB stick I have two options: FAT32(Default) and NTFS.

What do you recommend to me?

And what filesystem should I use for this shared partition (750GB)?

Comment: You should use NFTS for Windows and NTFS/FAT32 for data drive. I'm just wondering, why dual boot is required? You can virtualize either Linux or Windows and run both enviroments from one OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I use Rufus to create a USB stick I have two options: FAT32(Default) and NTFS.

That is the file system used by the USB installer. It has no bearing on the file system that the OS uses after installation.

For instance, current consumer Windows installations **always** uses NTFS as the main file system (for the main Windows system partition), regardless of whether the media you created in Rufus uses FAT32 or NTFS.

And likewise, Linux will be installed using `ext4` (most commonly), regardless of whether the installation media had NTFS or FAT32.

So, really, regardless of the file system you use for the installation media, you have pretty much only one option here, which will be to access your Windows file system from Linux using NTFS, because that's the only file system the Windows system partition will use.

> And what filesystem should I use for this shared partition (750GB)?

Now, for the data partition, you could probably use exFAT as the file system if you want to. But really, considering that your only choice for the Windows system partition will be NTFS, you might as well use NTFS everywhere, especially as the ntfs-3g driver from Linux is pretty much always available by default and very stable.

Comment: Generally it's ill advised to use ntfs on linux partition as permissions don't work the same

Comment: It is ok to use NTFS if only a shared data partition. But you must make sure Windows fast start up or hibernation is off. NTFS cannot be used for Linux partitions like / (root) or /home. In future exFAT will be better supported as Microsoft as released it and new driver will be in latest kernel, probably with 20.10, but may be back ported? The New Microsoft exFAT File-System Driver Is Set To Land With Linux 5.7
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=New-exFAT-For-Linux-5.7

Answer (score 1):

For the shared partition, yes, you can use NTFS.  In practice this is quite useable, although not something I would class as robust. (NTFS-3G implements reading and writing and has been around a long time. I could be wrong, but I think the issue is lack of a published spec for NTFS, so no one can be certain its all as per spec)

If its just for shared documents and you are not worried about extra attributes like ownership or large file sizes or squeezing the maximum performance, VFAT (FAT32) is a robust choice that is well supported, and simple.   If you can live with to limitations this would be my choice - the filesystem us well understood, ubiquitous and simple.